# Unable to serve react build's static folder using node server in one browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

i am serving the react build folder using express js

```
app.use(express.static("build"));
```

and for other request

```
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "build", "index.html"));});
```

but everytime the index.html file tries to access static folder's css and js files it responds back with index.html file

shockingly, it behaves normal in icognito mode

and when comment this code

```
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "build", "index.html"));});
```

it responds with following error in the console

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
const path = require('path');

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  const indexPath = path.join(__dirname, '../build', 'index.html');
  res.sendFile(indexPath);
});
```

Comment: I dont think that will work. I have tried. Thank you